# Voting system in asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a voting system on my website. The voting is about food, what food is getting ordered for tomorrow.

Now I want to make something like this (i made it with paint just to show you what im asking):

[image]

Is there anyway I can do this? Now... I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know how to start. All I'm asking from you, is to refer me somewhere/something, anything, that might help me with this.

Comment: Hi Coder 1993, can you be more specific?  Is your problem that you don't know how to display current voting results as coloured bars?   How far have you got with implementing the system?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there are many ways to do this. Unfortunately, this is not the right place to ask this type of question, as it is quite broad. SO is better for specific programming problems. I would think you'd be better off simply searching the web for existing solutions you can use, or perhaps programming tutorials to help you on your way. Later, you can come back and ask new questions here when you have a more specific problem you need help to solve.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a Project in Asp.net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372501/best-net-polling-survey-software

Comment: @SList I did the mos simpliest way to display the food votes like this: ex.  "Some food - 19, Some food 20" etc. But I want to display colored bars, which I don't know how

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the example about [Add a Quick Poll to Your Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973264.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably look at this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372501/best-net-polling-survey-software

and this

http://voting-asp.net/